# How to update the values in csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file and I want to change the values in the column `A1`, `A2` `A3` if the value is the half value or more of the total. In other words, for like Value 1 in A1, I want that 50 to be the total.
I want something like this:

[image: What I want]

And I have something like this:

[image: How it is]

I've only did this:

```py
df=pd.read_csv("book.csv",index_col=0)
print(df)
```

Comment: hi, please clarify, please show us what you tried, and please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My input file:**

```
A,A1,A2,A3
Total,100,200,300
Value1,100,200,300
Value2,40,200,140
Value3,100,50,100
Value4,100,90,50
Value5,30,20,300
```

Based on your comment:

> A1 the max value is 100 so if any other value in A1 is 50 or higher I want that value to be 100. In A2 the max value is 200 other values of A2 that are 100 or higher I want those value to be 200

You just need to use the [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method:

```
import pandas as pd
  
df = pd.read_csv('book.csv',index_col=0, delimiter=',')

#applying the condition using a lambda
df = df.apply(lambda x : [x.max() if i >= x.max()//2 else i for i in x])
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
  A      A1   A2   A3                 
Total   100  200  300
Value1  100  200  300
Value2   40  200  140
Value3  100   50  100
Value4  100   90   50
Value5   30   20  300
```

Comment: Please check the updated answer. I hope it works for you. If  it helps ,you can check and upvote the answer.

Comment: I don't know if I am doing anything wrong, but I don't get the same output as you. It is not changing anything.

Comment: Okay. I did a small change in my code. I hope it works for you. Are you reading the csv correctly. Just make sure your delimiter is correct by opening in notepad. By default it is ',' (comma), if not then just change in the `read_csv`. I have added the input file I used. Remember to check and accept if it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what do you mean by total value, but one way to access the values from your imported csv table is this:

```
import csv

with open('example.csv') as csv_file:
      csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = ',')
      for row in csv_reader:
            for i in range(len(row)):
                  #here goes your logical test to replace values
                  print(row[i])
```

Comment: You can change values using `row[i] = value` by the way

Comment: Okay what I mean is under A1 the max value is 100 so if any other value in A1 is 50 or higher I want that value to be 100.                                                                          In A2 the max value is 200 other values of A2 that are 100 or higher I want those value to be 200.